# Socket.io what room(s) is the socket in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am new to socket.io and unfamiliar with how to deal with their data structures.  According to another post, I need to use "socket.rooms" to find out what room a socket is in.  Yet if I print out "socket.rooms" in the console log, I get [Object object].  It is some type of object, but without any documentation on how to access that object properly, I am at a loss on what to do.

Very simple code below, I want the "????" to be the room they are in.  Obviously, they could be in more than one room, in which case I could build a loop... but for what I am building, they will only ever be in one room.

```
// Send Message
socket.on('game_update', function(data){

    var tStamp = Date.now();
    console.log(tStamp +" - "+ data.msg);

    io.in('????').emit('game_update', {time: tStamp, msg: data});
});
```

Comment: *I get [Object object].* — Are you printing `socket.rooms` or are you converting it to a string as you do with data.msg in your example (e.g. `"something" + socket.rooms`)?

Comment: In order to log the content of an object use JSON.stringifiy(obj)

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify`, that will discard most data types.

Comment: @Quentin - I was just printing socket.rooms which yields [Object object]

Comment: @Quentin - No sorry, I was wrong, reviewing my code, I did convert it to a string.  I tried just printing the object as you suggested, and that does show the elements inside the object.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Quentin I was able to figure it out.

```
console.log(socket.rooms); // prints all elements of the rooms object
```

A player in Room #82, looked something like:

```
{ '82': '82', 'oNKayk7Ny8GKh1-4AAAB': 'oNKayk7Ny8GKh1-4AAAB' }
```

The first element is the room, and the 2nd element is their browser cookie that socket.io creates.

To solve my issue, I need to figure out what element is the room, so '82' is inadequate for what I am doing.  I am making the 82 more specific, so I know that the property is the room I am referencing and not their cookie or something else.

```
socket.join("game_id="+data.game_id); // to join the room, but also id this from other properties
```

Then the final code I need is:

```
socket.on('game_update', function(data){

    console.log(socket.rooms); // for debug, prints the data
    var tStamp = Date.now();
    console.log(tStamp +" - "+ data.msg);

    var roomsObj = socket.rooms;

    for(i=0; i < Object.keys(roomsObj).length; i++)
    {
        if(roomsObj[Object.keys(roomsObj)[i]].split("=")[0] == "game_id")
        {
            //broadcasts to every room they are in, which begins in "game_id="
            io.in(roomsObj[Object.keys(roomsObj)[i]]).emit('game_update', {time: tStamp, msg: data});
        }
    }
});
```

Tested it, and it is working!

Comment: Solving your own problems is the best feeling in the world, great job! I was also trying to figure this out, luckily there're more resources on this now than in 2017!

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO has changed a lot through different versions. Think of it as a company with poor direction and non solid policies, constantly changing in detriment of their clients (the developers).

Digging into "io" I found this and I've been using it in my last project because I had your same problem:

```
io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id]
```

If on top of getting the rooms a socket is in you also need to get all sockets inside a room, use the following:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms['nameOfTheRoom'].sockets
```